How to use BoundFilter in aiogram 3.x
I'm trying to use a custom type of filter like BoundFilter in aiogram 2.x for filtering not allowed characters.
But recommended
class AllowedCharactersFilter(BoundFilter):
    async def check(self, message: types.Message):
        allowed_characters = set('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890')
        entered_text = message.text
        return all(char in allowed_characters for char in entered_text)

doesn't work. Because in aiogram 3.4 neither
from aiogram.dispather.filters import BoundFilter

nor
from aiogram.filters import BoundFilter

work.
Is BoundFilter to be imported in some another fashion?
I found that probably the solution is possible through using a BaseFilter imported from aiogram.filters. With creation of new directory under filters.
But a description of the procedure is not clear. Can comebody shed a light on the subject: How to filter unallowed characters in handlers of aiogram 3.4?

what means doesn't work? Do you get error? Show it in question (not in comments). We can't run your code, we can't see your computer, and we can't read in your mind - you have to describe all details. And it would be simpler if you would create minimal working code which we could simply copy and run - to test problem.

you forgot char c in word dispatcher - you have dispather - and this can be your problem (if you want to use 2.x)

documentation for aiogram 3.x shows class aiogram.filters.base.Filter as base class for own filter.

it seems 3.x has Magic Filters and maybe you would need only F.text.isalnum()

Thank you, furas. You are very close. I'm just experimenting with my solution. I need not a boolean value from a filter, but a string cleaned from not allowed characters, as a filter.  I'll be back with the final results

isalnum or isalpha do not suit because they do not let pass the needed me characters

if you need cleaned text then maybe you will need Router() but I never used it. And it will need different code instead of all(). Maybe "".join([char for char in message.text if char in self.allowed_characters])

I test some code with Middleware but it doesn't allow me to update message. At this moment I think the simplest is to run code directly in function def my_handler(message: Message): without using other aiogram.filters. Besides filters can only gives True/False - they can't modify message. Maybe later I find out how to use Middleware to modify message.

it seems 3.x has Magic Filters and you may need only F.text.isalnum()
from aiogram import F

@dp.message(F.text.isalnum())
async def my_handler(message: Message):
    #... code ...

EDIT:
I tested it and isalnum() allows only for messages with alphanumeric chars - but it means also native chars like ąść. Your function doesn't allow for native chars like ąść

And if you want to build filter then documentation shows aiogram.filters.base.Filter as base class for own filter.
#import string
from aiogram.filters import Filter

class MyFilter(Filter):

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        #self.allowed_characters = set(string.ascii_letters + string.digits)
        self.allowed_characters = set('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890')

    async def __call__(self, message: Message) -> bool:
        #not_allowed = set(message.text) - self.allowed_characters
        #return len(not_allowed) == 0
        return all(char in self.allowed_characters for char in message.text)


@dp.message(MyFilter())
async def my_handler(message: Message):
    #... code ...


EDIT:
Minimal working code which I used for tests:
import asyncio
import logging
import sys
from os import getenv

import aiogram
print('aiogram.__version__:', aiogram.__version__)

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, html
from aiogram.client.default import DefaultBotProperties
from aiogram.enums import ParseMode
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart, Filter
from aiogram.types import Message
from aiogram import F

TOKEN = getenv("TELEGRAM_TOKEN")

dp = Dispatcher()

class MyFilter(Filter):

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        #self.allowed_characters = set(string.ascii_letters + string.digits)
        self.allowed_characters = set('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890')

    async def __call__(self, message: Message) -> bool:
        #not_allowed = set(message.text) - self.allowed_characters
        #return len(not_allowed) == 0
        return all(char in self.allowed_characters for char in message.text)


@dp.message(CommandStart())
async def command_start_handler(message: Message) -> None:
    await message.answer(f"Hello, {html.bold(message.from_user.full_name)}!")


#@dp.message(F.text.isalnum())   # use one of them
@dp.message(MyFilter())   # use one of them
async def echo_handler(message: Message) -> None:
    try:
        print("echo_handler:", message.text)
        await message.send_copy(chat_id=message.chat.id)
    except TypeError:
        await message.answer("Nice try!")
        

async def main() -> None:
    bot = Bot(token=TOKEN, default=DefaultBotProperties(parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML))
    await dp.start_polling(bot)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, stream=sys.stdout)
    asyncio.run(main())

